# Local object pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

```
struct Temp
{
   CString one;
   CString two;
};

class Foo
{
   public:
      Temp obj;
      void somewhere();
}

void Foo::somewhere()
{
   void* pData = static_cast<void*>(&obj);
   OwnMethod(pData); // void OwnMethod(void*);
}
```

The question is:
Should I create `obj` on heap or this situation isn't dangerous (passing local class objects pointer)?

Comment: Entirely depends on what OwnMethod does with the pointer. This is a lifetime question, does the object being pointed to die before the pointer does. If so then you've got problems, otherwise you're OK.

Comment: Why instead of use OwnMethod(void*) don't you use templates?

Comment: Too little information to answer, vote to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `OwnMethod(pData)` stores the pointer somwhere for later use, that later use is not possible anymore, once the object on which `Foo::somewhere()` is called is destroyed.

If `OwnMethod(pData)` only access the pointed to data, you are safe.

Answer (score 3):

The member variable will last as long as the `Foo` object, so the pointer will be valid during the call to `OwnMethod`.

If that function stores a copy of the pointer somewhere, and something else uses that pointer later, then there is a danger that it might be accessed after the `Foo` (and therefore the pointer's target) have been destroyed. There are various ways to prevent that; as you say, one is to dynamically allocate the object, and then transfer or share ownership when it's passed to `OwnMethod`. Smart pointers, such as `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`, are a very good way to track ownership of dynamic objects.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, a lot of issues.

A complex object should't be passed to anything taking a void*.

Who wrote OwnMethod?

Why doesn't it take a pointer of type Foo*?

In fact why doesn't it take a reference of type Foo&?

If OwnMethod() may be required to accept objects of several different types then it should take a base class pointer or reference and use polymorphism.

However as far as the lifetime arguments go - obj will exist as long as the wrapping class does, so if the pointer is not used beyond the scope of OwnMethod this is ok.  If OwnMethod causes the pointer to be stored elsewhere beyond Foo's lifetime then you have an issue, and maybe obj should be allocated on the heap.  (And it might not even be appropriate for it to be a member of Foo at all.)